# How to format file path into two or more lines in R?

Tags: r, format, rstudio

I want my code to be more formated, I want following code:

```
Finaldata <- read_dta("F:/AuditGovernance/Audit firmGovernance/ProjectAA/1Data/GAuditFinal3Oct2016.dta")
```

to be formated as

```
Finaldata <- read_dta("F:/AuditGovernance/Audit firmGovernance/
                       ProjectAA/1Data/GAuditFinal3Oct2016.dta")
```

However R report this as error:

```
Error: This kind of input is not handled
```

so How can I write file path in two or more lines in R?

Comment: why do you want this?

Comment: `read_dta(file.path("F:/AuditGovernance/Audit firmGovernance",
                              "ProjectAA/1Data/GAuditFinal3Oct2016.dta"))`

Comment: @pyll because when you use vim as editor, it will auto rewrap the code when line length is over 80.

Comment: ah...ok.  well looks like you have three different but effective solutions to choose from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `paste` or `paste0`:

```
Finaldata <- read_dta(paste0(
  "F:/AuditGovernance/Audit firmGovernance/",
  "ProjectAA/1Data/GAuditFinal3Oct2016.dta"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do this, but here ya go....

```
Finaldata <- read_dta(paste("F:/AuditGovernance/Audit firmGovernance/",
                       "ProjectAA/1Data/GAuditFinal3Oct2016.dta", sep = ""))
```